# Representing Abstract JSON Objects as models in Java

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Ok so I am making API requests to retrieve certain things like movies, songs, or to ping the server. However all of these responses are contained within the same response JSON object that has varying fields depending on the response. Below are three examples.

ping

```
{
    "response" : {
        "status" : "ok",
        "version" : "0.9.1"
    }
}
```

getIndexes

```
{
    "response" : {
        "status" : "ok",
        "version" : "0.9.1",
        "indexes" : {
            "index" : [ { 
                "name" : "A",
                "movie" : [ {
                    "id" : "150",
                    "name" : "A Movie"
                }, {
                    "id" : "2400",
                    "name" : "Another Movie"
                } ]
            }, {
                "name" : "S",
                "movie" : [ { 
                    "id" : "439",
                    "name" : "Some Movie"
                }, {
                    "id" : "209",
                    "name" : "Some Movie Part 2"
                } ]
            } ]
        }
    }
}
```

getRandomSongs

```
{
    "response" : {
        "status" : "ok"
        "version" : "0.9.1"
        "randomSongs" : {
            "song": [ {
                "id" : "72",
                "parent" : "58",
                "isDir" : false,
                "title" : "Letter From Yokosuka",
                "album" : "Metaphorical Music",
                "artist" : "Nujabes",
                "track" : 7,
                "year" : 2003,
                "genre" : "Hip-Hop",
                "coverArt" : "58",
                "size" : 20407325,
                "contentType" : "audio/flac",
                "suffix" : "flac",
                "transcodedContentType" : "audio/mpeg",
                "transcodedSuffix" : "mp3",
                "duration" : 190,
                "bitRate" : 858,
                "path" : "Nujabes/Metaphorical Music/07 - Letter From Yokosuka.flac",
                "isVideo" : false,
                "created" : "2015-06-06T01:18:05.000Z",
                "albumId" : "2",
                "artistId" : "0",
                "type" : "music"
            }, {
                "id" : "3135",
                "parent" : "3109",
                "isDir" : false,
                "title" : "Forty One Mosquitoes Flying In Formation",
                "album" : "Tame Impala",
                "artist" : "Tame Impala",
                "track" : 4,
                "year" : 2008,
                "genre" : "Rock",
                "coverArt" : "3109",
                "size" : 10359844,
                "contentType" : "audio/mpeg",
                "suffix" : "mp3",
                "duration" : 258,
                "bitRate" : 320,
                "path" : "Tame Impala/Tame Impala/04 - Forty One Mosquitoes Flying In Formation.mp3",
                "isVideo" : false,
                "created" : "2015-06-29T21:50:16.000Z",
                "albumId" : "101",
                "artistId" : "30",
                "type" : "music" 
            } ]
        }
    }
}
```

So basically my question is, how should I structure my model classes to use for parsing these responses? At the moment I have an abstract response object that only contains fields for the status and version. However, by using this approach I will need a response class that extends this abstract class for ever request I make (e.g. AbstractResponse, IndexesResponse, RandomSongsResponse). Also, some models with the same name may have different fields depending on the API request made. I would prefer to avoid making a model class for every possible scenario.

And as an extra note, I am using GSON for JSON serialization/deserialization and Retrofit to communicate with the API.

Comment: Create 3 classes Ping, Movie and Songs. Parse the JSON and simply try to access "index" or "randomSongs" if you don't get a JSONException (null) than you create the appropriate class if both fail than you know it's Ping.

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you mean exactly. How would you write these classes?

Comment: I personally think an extending class for each response is the cleanest way possible in this scenario. I know it sucks and seems there oughta be a best way, but probably any other approach would result in an over-complication .